があっての? is it the same as あっての?

勝算があっての判断か

A character is commenting on the other's plan and says this.  Does があっての here have nuance as Nounあってのnoun?

Related; see examples of があっての: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3281/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74267/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85840/9831, and examples of NあってのN: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6504/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8303/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3274/9831

They are more or less interchangeable, but there are different tendencies in usage. In AあってのB, the absence of が adds a literary flavor to the sentence (が was not a subject marker in classical Japanese). And the use of classical grammar also suggests that an idiomatic meaning is intended. On the other hand, AがあってのB is a phrase that follows contemporary Japanese grammar.
Therefore, we can say the following:

When the phrase means "A is what makes B possible" or "B is impossible without A", AあってのB tends to sound more idiomatic and sophisticated, but it's not wrong at all to add が.
When the phrase means something simpler such as "B based on A" or "B after A", AがあってのB tends to be chosen, but が may still be dropped to add a dignified flavor to the sentence.

I think you can sense this difference by looking at the links posted by Chocolate.
